# ¿Combinar filas en una sola columna en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Estoy intentando combinar todas las líneas en una sola columna. Tengo algo así:

```
id=c(1,2,3,4)
col1=c("aaa","bbb","ccc","aaa")
col2=c("bbb","ccc"," "," ")
col3=c("ccc"," "," "," ")
col4=c("aaa","bbb","ccc"," ")
dt=data.frame(id,col1,col2,col3); dt

   id col1 col2 col3
1  1  aaa  bbb  ccc
2  2  bbb  ccc  
3  3  ccc  
4  4  aaa
```

Necesito que se vea algo así;

```
id  col
1   aaa
1   bbb
2   bbb
2   ccc
3   ccc
4   aaa
```

Alguna sugerencia? Necesito resolver este problema rápido :(

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Rápido o Urgente son malos adjetivos para usar en esta comunidad, además deberíamos pedirte que muestres lo que hubieras intentado antes, para que no sea esta una de esa preguntas "hagan mi tarea".

Answer (score 0):

Podrias llevarla al formato deseado con la funcion pivot_longer

```
library(tidyverse)

dt = dt %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("col"),
               values_to = "col",
               names_to = "tipo_col")
```

El argumento cols hace referencia a las columnas que quieres pasar a una sola columna, y los argumentos values_to y names_to, son los nombres para las columnas que pasaron a este formato, en este caso, yo los llame "col" y "tipo_col", pero puedes llamarlos como gustes.

Finalmente puedes eliminar la variable tipo_col si no es de tu interés

```
dt = dt %>% select(-tipo_col)
```